# Cómo puedo obtener este valor href con Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy tratando de obtener el enlace de este href, y he probado todas las opciones de las respuestas que he encontrado en este foro y ¡nada me funciona!
el href es de un video de youtube incrustado de youtube, tal vez por eso no me ha sido fácil extraer esa url

**El HTML es este:**

```html
<div class="ytp-title-text"><a class="ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink" target="_blank" data-sessionlink="feature=player-title" tabindex="-1" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eajVzIXZCsw">Turbulencias-Kabasaki,Juseph,Saiko,Quevedo,LoveYi,Jader,YagoRoche,Fabbio,LaPantera,Bless</a><div class="ytp-title-subtext"><a class="ytp-title-channel-name" target="_blank" href=""></a></div></div>
```

**Y mi ultimo intento fué este:**

```html
#YOUTUBE VIDEO EMBED
divfather = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[@class="ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink"]')
video = divfather.get_attribute('href')
print(video)
```

Pero siempre me sale este error, como si nunca lo pudiera encontrar o algo así:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class="ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink"]"}

Comment: El xpath es correcto. Casi con toda seguridad que el elemento aún no esté creado en el DOM en el momento que lo buscas. Como no se puede reproducir el error con la información que das, no hay más que te pueda decir.

Comment: La cosa es que no sabes si lo que buscas se carga de forma dinámica con JS y por eso no aparece cuando lo revisas con el script python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado su problema posiblemente se deba a los siguientes factores:

1. El elemento no se encuentra en el dom.
2. No es visible en la pagina ni el dom.
3. Se encuentra en un iframe.

Yo le recomiendo crear un xpath usando los nodos del dom y que llegue al //a usando parent, ascendant, descendant, following por ejemplo.